# Count properties of JavaScript object

Tags: jquery

My question is short and concise.

I need count the attributes of Json object, for example

```
 obj={
      name:'Jhon',
      age:25
 }
```

This must return 2, one for 'name' and ohter for 'age'.
I try use.

```
 obj.count();
 obj.length();
```

But nothing...

The all solutions that I found in internet was for count elements of array.

Thanks to all!

Comment: That's not JSON. That's JavaScript. (Specifically, it's a JavaScript object initializer.) [JSON](http://json.org) is a non-code, textual data format. And in JavaScript they're called "properties," not "attributes" (not a criticism, "attributes" is a general term -- just letting you know what the precise term is).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try **[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, There is no built in `length` property or method on Javascript object.

```
var propCount = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

*Note that there is a Shim you need to add in your source code for added support for some older browsers (ex: IE < 9) . Read the documentation link from MDN*

Comment: I would advise not to touch Object.prototype, you will be affecting *everything* else with unpredictable results.

Comment: @LexLythius yeah you are right, it is not advisable at all to extend built in prots

Comment: Also, note that [Object.keys only works with modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_support)

Comment: yes but there is a shim in MDN which you can add to your source in case not available.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the `Object.keys(obj).length` solution, here's a polyfill for browsers that don't support Object.keys.

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(o,k,r){
    r=[];
    for(k in o){
        r.hasOwnProperty.call(o,k) && r.push(k);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You would need to put `return r` outside the for loop.